# Gerrit Error: commit subject >65 characters; use shorter first paragraph

Tags: git, gerrit

We started to use the Gerrit code review recently. Sometimes when you make a simple commit and try to make a push to Gerrit, this error is displayed:

```
   remote rejected
   commit subject >65 characters; use shorter first paragraph
```

I looked in the web but did not find how to solve this problem. I tried to make an amend in the previous commit and reduce the size of the commit message, but the error remains.

What kind of error is that? And how to solve it? Is there some Gerrit configuration about the size of the commit message?

Comment: "how to solve this problem" is right there in the error message: `use shorter first paragraph`... specifically, the first line should be <= 65 characters...

Answer (score 4):

The first paragraph of your commit message should be 65 characters.

You may split it for a longer text:

```
initial commit message <65 chars

my long commit message with a lot of information,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Suspendisse metus nulla, blandit eget aliquam sed, tincidunt
nec turpis. Ut quis gravida augue, scelerisque tempor risus...
```

Comment: It´s true.  I saw now that this is just a warning, you can push to gerrit, the problema to push to Gerrit was another massage that I haven't seen.

Comment: You are right.  That is just warning.  There is another error. I noticed it after wasting an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have installed **commit-message-length-validator** plugin. By default, commit message max subject length is 65, max line length is 70.

You could change the default setting on gerrit.config or you could remove/disable this plugin.

Comment: I would really love to see if there is a way to perform this check at client level.

Answer (score 0):

The same message appears to me, but it doesn't reflect the real issue. because I already added a message less than 50 chars.

> remote: commit 6879a64: warning: subject >50 characters; use shorter first paragraph

The real issue was when I was trying to push my commit to a specific branch but I don't add the branch name.

the solution is so simply adding the branch name with the push command.

```
git review -R branch_name
```